# Spreadsheet API : Get cell entry from specific cell address

Tags: java, google-sheets-api

how can I get a `CellEntry` given a specific cell address e.g in `A1` notation. For example,

```
String address = "A1";
CellEntry cellEntry = getCellEntry(address);

public CellEntry getCellEntry(String address){

    //- What can I do inside here

}
```

Previously, I fetch everything using `CellFeed` and iterating using `cellFeed.getEntries` to get each CellEntry and filter out based on cell address. But I think it will have a performance issues since my spreadsheet is large. Any idea ? I'm using Java.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got two approaches here :

**Method 1**

Using `CellQuery`

```
public CellEntry getCellEntry(URL cellFeedUrl, Integer colNum, Integer rowNum){

    CellQuery cellQuery = new CellQuery(cellFeedUrl);
    cellQuery.setMaximumCol(colNum);
    cellQuery.setMinimumCol(colNum);
    cellQuery.setMaximumRow(rowNum);
    cellQuery.setMinimumRow(rowNum);

    CellFeed cellFeed = service.getFeed(cellQuery, CellFeed.class)              
    return cellFeed.getEntries().get(0);
}
```

Note : The `setMaximumCol` and `setMinimumCol` must be the same to get the specified column. Similar with the `setMaximumRow` and `setMinimumRow`.

**Method 2**

Using `CellFeedURL`

```
public CellEntry getCellEntry(WorksheetEntry worksheet, Integer colNum, Integer rowNum){

    if (colNum == null || rowNum == null){
        //- do something
    }
    else {

        String row = "?min-row=" + rowNum + "&max-row=" + rowNum;
        String col = "&min-col=" + colNum + "&max-col=" + colNum;

        URL cellFeedUrl = new URI(worksheet.getCellFeedUrl().toString()
        + row + col).toURL();
        CellFeed cellFeed = service.getFeed(cellFeedUrl, CellFeed.class);
        return cellFeed.getEntries().get(0);
    }
}
```

Note : Based on [Google Spreadsheet API : Changing content of a cell](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/data#fetch_specific_rows_or_columns)

Personally I think the second method is better.